# How does web browsers transfer Passwords to origin servers?

Tags: browser, password-protection

My question is simple regarding password security..

As a web application developer using PHP for example, I may design a html form that accepts a username and password and post them to the webserver using the POST method..

My question is:
1- When a user enters a password for this form on a web browser, does this web browser send the password over the network as plaintext and thus insecurely?

2-isn't it possible that the web browser saves all passwords and sends them to the third party that design the web browser?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, unless you're using https, which encrypts everything sent between the server and the client.
2. Sure, but you could use a network sniffer to verify that the browser sends no information to third party servers.

Comment: Then What difference it makes if my Web application uses basic authentication or digest authentication..In both cases my credentials will be send as plain test over the network , right?

Comment: If you use Basic Auth over HTTP then the password will be obfuscated, but not encrypted.  If you use Digest Auth over HTTP, it will be hashed, so the password isn't sent at all, but rather a hash of (the password plus some other data).  If you use either type of Auth over HTTPS, everything will be encrypted.

Comment: @RichieHindle : but what if the web browser does not do such hashing of obfuscating? will the password in such case be send always as  plain text over the network no matter of what authentication method my web app. is using?

Comment: Basic Auth always obfuscates passwords, or it wouldn't be Basic Auth.  Digest Auth always hashes passwords, or it wouldn't be Digest Auth.  If you're writing your own login system using plain old HTML forms and cookies, then the password will be sent in the clear.

Answer (score 1):

1. It's sent unencrypted (though possibly obfuscated) if you're using HTTP, or encrypted if you're using HTTPS.
2. Any mainstream web browser won't do that, no.  It would be discovered within seconds of the browser being released.  However, it's possible for such a leak to occur by other means, for example:

   o A rogue browser plugin

   o A rogue proxy on the user's network (if you're using HTTP)

   o A keylogger on the user's machine